# Python reading only one line and ignoring others

Tags: python

Read a file and search for a particular set of numbers, line by line, and split them into new files according to that particular number.

file exp:

```
000002.4794 4600 9127 0320.  08/21    
000001.4794 4600 0376 2836.  12/22
```

current code:

```
    for filename in path.glob(f"*{extension}"):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if '4794 46' in line:
                newpath = r'C:\RI\OUTBOX\479446'
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)
                    with open('479446//t'+now+'_visa_479446.dat', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(line)
```

problem:

The code only read the first line of the particular number and ignored the rest.

How do I make it so it does not ignore other lines after finding the first set of particular number.

Comment: try `for line in infile.readlines()` instead of just `for line in infile`.

Answer (score 1):

What happen if `newpath` existed?

```
for filename in path.glob(f"*{extension}"):
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if '4794 46' in line:
            newpath = r'C:\RI\OUTBOX\479446'
            if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                os.makedirs(newpath)
            with open('479446//t'+now+'_visa_479446.dat', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                outfile.write(line)
```